# C# How to disable linux terminal user input during the execution of a Console Application

Tags: c#, linux, terminal, .net-core, console-application

When I run my console application in windows, unless I'm actively reading input (i.e. via Console.Read...) nothing happens when I type in the console.

When I'm running **the same** console application in linux, whatever I type is inserted in the middle of what the application is writing to the console at the time.

Is there any way to prevent/capture/flush the user input in the terminal during the execution of the program?

Comment: Please provide sample code and outputs on different systems. It can be hard to help without code.

Comment: It's a pretty large application, I'm going to try to create a simpler one that illustrates the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can disable echo on the shell before running your program and re-enable it afterwards:

```
$ stty_bak=`stty -g`
$ stty -echo
$ <run your command / program>
$ stty $stty_bak
```